# Substrate call raw transaction

Tags: transactions, rpc, custom-rpc

I created a custom function in a custom RPC call to send a raw transaction :

```
fn send_raw_transaction(&self, bytes: Bytes) -> FutureResult<TxHash<P>> {
        let slice = &bytes.0[..];
        if slice.len() == 0 {
            return Box::pin(future::err(internal_err("transaction data is empty")));
        }

        let extend = rlp::encode(&slice);
        let block_hash = BlockId::hash(self.client.info().best_hash);

        let ext = "05000046ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a30".as_bytes();
        let xt = match Decode::decode(&mut &ext[..]) {
            Ok(xt) => xt,
            Err(_) => return Box::pin(future::err(internal_err("cannot access runtime api"))),
        };
        println!("extrinsic : {:?}",ext);

        return Box::pin(
            self.pool
                .submit_one(&block_hash, TransactionSource::Local, xt)
                .map_err(|err| {
                    internal_err(format!("submit transaction to pool failed: {:?}", err))
                }),
        );
    }
}
```

`05000046ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a30`

This should be a balances.transfer call.

When I try to call this method I just receive an error :

*submit transaction to pool failed: RuntimeApi("Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\n\n    0: 0x113908 - !rust_begin_unwind\n")
RpcError: -32603: submit transaction to pool failed: RuntimeApi("Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\n\n    0: 0x113908 - !rust_begin_unwind\n")*

Do you have an idea, where this error come from ?

thank you.

Comment: Around this error in your log you should also see the actual panic that is printed into the log as well. What does it say?

Comment: @bkchr the full message : `2022-08-23 10:28:36        RPC-CORE: sendRawTransaction(extrinsic: Bytes): U256:: -32603: submit transaction to pool failed: RuntimeApi("Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm ``unreachable`` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\n\n    0: 0x113908 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n")
RpcError: -32603: submit transaction to pool failed: RuntimeApi("Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm ``unreachable`` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\n\n    0: 0x113908 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n")`

Comment: It should be somewhere before this message in the log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`05000046ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a30` is an encoded call, but it is not an encoded extrinsic. So you won't be able to submit that into the pool, the format is incorrect.

Above you have

`<call index><call data>`

any extrinsic is in the format of

`<compact length><version><signature (if signed)><extension data><call index><call data>`

Since the length is missing (and then the version flag with the signed/unsigned bit), the runtime cannot decode it to submit to the pool.